# For a POST request, where is the entry point in NET Core Web application (so that I can place a breakpoint there)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

My Postman POST request never reaches its public endpoint in the controller. The response I get back from my web application (running on a localhost port) is the app's static index.html page.

I want to debug what happens to the request by placing a breakpoint at the application's request "entry point", and figure out why it never reaches my controller. Where should I place the break point?

Endpoint. Please note this is a public endpoint:

```
[HttpPost("endpointName")]
public async Task<ActionResult> myEndpoint() {
    return Ok();
}
```

Postman POST request: https://localhost:44123/api/endpointName

Authorization: No Auth

Other requests (both public and private endpoints) seem to work fine.

**Please let me know where I can place a breakpoint to debug this request.**

Comment: I know this is probably a stupid comment put you are specifing a POST VERB in Postman right?

Comment: What is response http status code? You are calling with /api/. Does controller has this specification? Did you try adding Route("myEndpoint") top of method?

Comment: I don't need to spell it, I just select it from the dropdown: https://i.imgur.com/AT3UWqy.png

Comment: @BerkayYaylacı Other endpoints with the same format are working.

Comment: What was the http status code at postman? 404,405,500? @bigShaq

Comment: @BerkayYaylacı 200 OK

Comment: Please show the relevant configuration from your Program.cs or Startup.cs, ideally in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: @mason - added those files in the description

Comment: Have you tried looking at the log output if you set Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft to Debug? It gives you quite a lot of info about how the .NET routing middleware resolves the route. This does assume you have a logger set up, of course...

Comment: Please do not add the files as a link to content hosted on another site. Those links tend to break, and then your question becomes useless to future viewers that come across it. Put the relevant text of those files directly in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED:

Stupid mistake.

I forgot to add "myEndpoints" after /api/

https://localhost:44123/api/**myEndpoints**/endpointName

Answer (score -1):

Check for the naming error in your API, also check whether you have specified same name in any other file as your controller.

Comment: Answers should be in the form of "You are having this problem because of this. Do this to fix it." Text such as "Check this and check that" are acceptable as comments as they lead to clarification of the question, but rarely make good answers. See [answer] for more tips on what makes a good answer.

Comment: Checked what you mentioned.